# XCode dependency: incompatible tools version

Tags: xcode, dependencies

I have cloned a repo for an iOS and am having a problem building / running the app. `stripe-ios` was added to the project as a package dependency and I am receiving the following error when resolving package dependencies:

[image]

When first running the app, since it has been a while since using XCode, I did the following:

- `sudo gem install cocoapods` to update cocoapods
- `pod install`
- `pod update`

I am currently using Xcode 11.4 on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

I thought maybe this had something to do with the command line tools so I updated that with no luck.  I'm afraid I don't know what "tools version" and "root" are referring to. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further research, I've concluded that this was a dumb question.  Just had to update XCode > 12.  Thank you, and sorry